# New Filtered View in Google Analytics not recording data

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a filtered view that blocks all of the spam, bots, etc. from my original unfiltered view. The problem I am receiving ever since I created this view is:
Sometimes I see some real time data, but no data is actually recorded for historical purposes.

Here's a screenshot of the Filtered Audience Overview:

[image: Filtered Audience Overview]

---

Here's a screenshot of the warning Google Analytics is giving me, but it's not really true:

[image: warning Google Analytics is giving me]

Also, the stats for the unfiltered view haven't changed at all since adding this view.

How do I fix this asap?

Comment: We'd need to know more about the view you created and filters, can you provide a screenshot(s) for that?

Comment: This. Your real time view will show all data coming in. But if your view is filtering all that traffic out then it'll be dropped before it's recorded. It might be handy to see your filter rules too.

Comment: [Image of filter for the filtered view](http://i.imgur.com/s04Zt9K.png) I have so many other people using this site yet, nothing is being recorded so this is strange. The following are the domains being blocked (using examples):
examplesite1\.com|examplesite2\.com|developer's localhost|our hosting server|spammer IP address. This doesn't make sense because i'm not blocking "my" internet IPs traffic and I have viewed the site many times, and I am not blocking my many friends and other users who tell me that they use my site, but it's not being recorded. Why?

Comment: Oh, and the google known spam block checkbox is checked for the filtered view - no filters or blocks are set for the unfiltered view. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I see the issue now: the hosts that you "include" should be _valid_ ones, like I described in my answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56713/could-somebody-hijack-my-google-analytics-for-a-site/56719#56719), and [this](https://moz.com/blog/stop-ghost-spam-in-google-analytics-with-one-filter) article describes in more detail, whereas you seem to be including the ones you want to block, and Google is likely already blocking those with _exclude traffic from known bots and spiders_ checked, hence nothing is being reported.

Comment: Ah okay so basically it should be our website|our ip|our dev ips ? Wherever we put the GA script?

Comment: Yes, but I'd suggest first taking a look with the Google checkbox alone for a while to look at the referrers as that article discusses, since you might be accidentally excluding a valid source, and to gauge whether it's still necessary. Maybe you can add an answer below as per the above and accept that so this question can be considered closed. Thanks.

Comment: I'll try that and see, though it looks like some spammy ips were getting though despite the checkbox. The filtered view, despite still saying that it may be a duplicate, is now working. Thanks.