# What can I do if someone else used my Google Analytics tracking code to spam me?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, spam

Today when I'm checking my Google Analytics report, I got the warning:

> Google Search Quality has detected that one or more sites associated with the property ****** likely has been compromised.
>
> A 3rd party might have modified existing content or added new spam content to your site. To protect your users, Google Search results might label your site as "This site may be hacked". Google Search might also serve an older, safe version of your site.
>
> The following site(s) appear to be serving compromised pages:
>       ******.com/
>
> A compromised site can harm users by serving malicioius software (malware), collecting personal information, or by redirecting users to sites they didn't intend to visit.
>
> You should take action immediately. If you already use Search Console, log in and check the Security Issues section to see specific examples of the pages that are affected and fix the issue. If you’re not familiar with Search Console, learn more about the steps you should follow to fix your site on http://google.com/webmasters/hacked.

What should I do in this case?

This is really dirty, this website stole my code and removed my ads code but forgot to remove my GA tracking code.

Comment: I read this as someone recreated your site on another domain name, removed the ad code but not the GA code, then got hacked. Is that right? Just making sure we are clear so that you get the best possible answer. Cheers!!

Comment: Assuming I read things correctly: The first thing I would do is create a DCMA complaint and describe that they are using your GA code and you got a notice. Not sure what will come of it. Also try the Google forums. Google engineers/employees often troll these sites and sometimes will respond. Otherwise, sometimes they will take action without responding.

Comment: @closetnoc yes, exactly.

Comment: I do not think this is Google Analytics...it is Search Console. New pages are on your site...login and see if your web server has been hacked.

Comment: Who's website is lable with "This site may be hacked". in Google search? Your's or someone else website? If someone else website is compromised then just ignore the message and [add filter](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en) so your analytic stats count only your website hits, then fill a [DMCA a request](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard) as closetnoc said.

Comment: Couldnt you just open a new property with an entirely new tracking code?

Comment: See my answer here:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56713/could-somebody-hijack-my-google-analytics-for-a-site

Comment: See also https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/someone-else-is-using-our-google-analytics-tracking-code-number-what-do-we-do and https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/91045/google-analytics-how-to-remove-unwanted-entries

Answer (score 2):

In google analytics, you can create a filter to exclude all traffic to the hostname that has your GA code.

To do so click on admin > All filters > Add filter

- Give a name to the filter
- Click on your website in the list and click add
- select filter type: "exclude"
- Choose "traffic to the hostname"
- Choose "that contain"
- Enter the domain name of the website that stole your Google Analytics code.